# Encode unicode codepoints to UTF-8 manually

Tags: c#, unicode, utf-8

I want to encode unicode codepoints to UTF-8 manually. I wrote the following C# code. I tested it with some cases I know, but I would like to know if it's correct for all inputs. I know that Unicode codepoints are undefined beyond `0x10FFFF` ,but I don't care about that. Therefore the output of my method might be more than 4 bytes.

```
private byte[] CodePointToUtf8 (int codepoint)
{
    if (codepoint < 0x80) {
        return new byte[]{ 
            (byte)(codepoint) 
        };
    } else if (codepoint < 0x800) {         
        return new byte[]{ 
            (byte)(0xC0 | (codepoint << 21 >> 27)), 
            (byte)(0x80 | (codepoint << 26 >> 26))
        };
    } else if (codepoint < 0x10000) {
        return new byte[] {
            (byte)(0xE0 | (codepoint << 16 >> 28)),
            (byte)(0x80 | (codepoint << 20 >> 26)) ,
            (byte)(0x80 | (codepoint << 26 >> 26))
        };
    } else if (codepoint < 0x200000) {
        return new byte[] {
            (byte)(0xF0 | (codepoint << 11 >> 29)),
            (byte)(0x80 | (codepoint << 14 >> 26)),
            (byte)(0x80 | (codepoint << 20 >> 26)) ,
            (byte)(0x80 | (codepoint << 26 >> 26))
        };
    } else if (codepoint < 0x4000000) {
        return new byte[] {
            (byte)(0xF8 | (codepoint << 6 >> 30)),
            (byte)(0x80 | (codepoint << 8 >> 26)),
            (byte)(0x80 | (codepoint << 14 >> 26)),
            (byte)(0x80 | (codepoint << 20 >> 26)) ,
            (byte)(0x80 | (codepoint << 26 >> 26))
        };
    } else {
        return new byte[] {
            (byte)(0xFC | (codepoint << 1 >> 31)),
            (byte)(0x80 | (codepoint << 2 >> 26)),
            (byte)(0x80 | (codepoint << 8 >> 26)),
            (byte)(0x80 | (codepoint << 14 >> 26)),
            (byte)(0x80 | (codepoint << 20 >> 26)) ,
            (byte)(0x80 | (codepoint << 26 >> 26))
        };
    }
}
```

Bonus question: Is there an build in way to do that?

Comment: Did you test with emojis? What you implemented is UTF-8-1993, but the current version is UTF-8-2003 (see Wikipedia), and the latter version encodes emojis differently.

Comment: I tested some emojis (eg U+1F600) and it worked for them. If I understand this correctly UTF-8-2003 is included in UTF-8-1993 since 10FFFF (last codepoint 2003) < 1FFFFF (last 4 byte codepoint 1993). But maybe I got this completely wrong?

Comment: Now that I think of it, I'm the one who is completely wrong. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the code is correct for all valid code points. I was first confused about the double shifts, since I have never seen them before, but they do their job well. Other authors typically do a single `>>` followed by a bit mask, e.g. `(codepoint >> 12) & 0x3F` to skip the 12 bits to the right and take the next 6 bits. That way, the numbers can be verified more easily, since they are smaller. Plus, all the `01xxxxxx` bytes have the same bitmask.

Your code omits some validity checks:

- `codepoint` could be `< 0`
- `codepoint` could be between `0xD800` and `0xDFFF`

Other than these, it is perfect.

I know for sure that this conversion is built-in into C#, I just don't know where. Try loading a file into a string using the UTF-8 encoding. During that loading, the built-in conversion code gets called.

Comment: A few moments ago I found out that at least in Unity3D where this code was supposed to run the rightshift >> is the arithmetical rightshift which means that a negative number shifted righ will be padded with 1s instead of 0s. Because of this I'm not longer sure if my code is correct.

Comment: To fix this, you should declare `codepoint` as `unsigned int`. This also frees you from checking whether `codepoint < 0`.

Comment: Oh, and since the `codepoint < 0x80` branch doesn't contain any shifts, your code is fine right now. Just by coincidence, but nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

### UTF-8 Verification .NET

> *Bonus question: Is there an build in way to do that?*

There is a built-in way to encode an unicode code point to UTF-8. I have checked some of the results against the [UTF-8 Specification 2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description), and I believe this method complies to it. Another interesting link is the [UTF8Encoding Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/utf8encoding.cs,c18e1492beee78eb) to see how this encoding works.

```
private byte[] CodePointToUtf8_BuiltIn(int codepoint)
{
    return new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(new[] { (char)codepoint });
}
```

If we loop through the code points and filter out surrogates, we get some discrepancies between your algorithm and the built-in one.

```
internal const char HIGH_SURROGATE_START = '\ud800';
internal const char HIGH_SURROGATE_END = '\udbff';
internal const char LOW_SURROGATE_START = '\udc00';
internal const char LOW_SURROGATE_END = '\udfff';        

for (int i = 0; i <= 0x10FFFF; i++)
{
    if (i >= HIGH_SURROGATE_START && i <= HIGH_SURROGATE_END) continue;
    if (i >= LOW_SURROGATE_START && i <= LOW_SURROGATE_END) continue;

    var op = CodePointToUtf8(i);
    var net = CodePointToUtf8_BuiltIn(i);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(net, op);
}
```

Here's a way to display the differences

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendLine("0x" + i.ToString("X4"));
builder.AppendLine(string.Join(" - ", op.Select(x => Convert.ToString(x, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'))));
builder.AppendLine(string.Join(" - ", net.Select(x => Convert.ToString(x, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'))));
var text = builder.ToString();
```

And some differences

```
0x00A0
11000010 - 11100000
11000010 - 10100000

0x0400
11110000 - 10000000
11010000 - 10000000

0x0720
11111100 - 11100000
11011100 - 10100000

..
```

Could you explain the differences?